# How to create an enter key triggered Edit control which clicks a button on pressing enter in win32 api?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I want to create an edit control that behaves in the following manner:
While user is entering text in the edit control, when enter is pressed by the user, it clicks a button.
I searched a lot but found nothing that helps.
How to do it in C++ Win32 API.

Comment: This is the same question you asked before, just with less information. Why did you delete the previous question only to re-ask a worse version of it? Maybe you shouldn't ignore users that previously recommended that you take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Have you solved your problem yet？

Comment: I just subclassed the edit control

Answer (score 0):

Simply give the Button control the [`BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/button-styles) style, then it will react to <kbd>Enter</kbd> presses automatically.

Otherwise, you would have to [subclass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview) the Edit control to catch `WM_KEY(DOWN|UP)` messages sent to it (don't catch them in the parent window's WndProc), check for `VK_RETURN`, and if detected then send a [`BM_CLICK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bm-click) message to the Button control.

Comment: No point in subclassing the edit control. Just set its style correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: "don't do that."

Create a dialog containing the edit control and button. Make sure the edit control's `ES_WANTRETURN` style is turned *off*, and the button's `BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON` style is turned *on*.

`ES_WANTRETURN` controls whether the edit control processes a carriage return/enter key (`VK_RETURN` keystroke). With it turned on, the edit control processes the keystroke itself (it becomes a new-line in the edit control). Probably obvious, but `ES_WANTRETURN` is generally only useful for a multi-line edit control.

With `ES_WANTRETURN` turned off, the enter/return keystroke is passed to the parent (the dialog box). That will process an enter as pressing the default button (if there is one).

Comment: I believe this is mostly correct, as long as the EDIT control is a child of a dialog. Though [just because you're a control doesn't mean that you're necessarily inside a dialog box](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070820-00/?p=25513). As much as I'd like to up-vote this or Remy's [proposed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71514822/1889329), that's a crucial detail missing from the question, so I voted to close it instead. The answer depends on detail missing from the question.